# How to generate a list of random numbers with the 5% occurance of particular values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to generate a list of 100 random integer numbers. However, I need to create the values in such way that large values occur only in 5% of cases, while the rest of values are equal to 0.

This is how I generate such list. How can I specify that large values (i.e. around 180000 should occur in 5% of cases?

```
import random
random.sample(range(0, 180000), 100)
```

For example:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...,0, 0, 170000]
```

Comment: What do you mean by large values? Larger than 0?

Comment: Exactly 5% or 5% on average?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Exactly 5%

Comment: @Selcuk: I refer to the values shown in m example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so like this:

```
import numpy as np

nb_vals = 100
large_values = np.arange(150000, 180000, 5000) # from 150 000 to 180 000 by 5 000 steps
your_list = [
    0 if np.random.rand() < 0.95 # 95% chance of 0
    else np.random.choice(large_values) # 5% chance of random element from large_values
    for _ in range(nb_vals) # nb_val independant draws
]
```

If you need another list of possible values, just change `large_values` into any kind of 1D structure (list, tuple, numpy array) and `choice` will select one randomly (uniform distribution). explore [choice's docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) if you want more than 1 value or another distribution on large_values chosen

If you want exactly 5% here's an alternative way:

```
import numpy as np

nb_vals = 100
ratio = 0.05
large_values = np.arange(150000, 180000, 5000) # from 150 000 to 180 000 by 5 000 steps
target_size = int(ratio * nb_vals) # how many large values do you want

result = np.zeros((nb_vals,))

perm = np.random.permutation(nb_vals)[: target_size] # sample locations
vals = np.random.choice(large_values, size=target_size, replace=True)
# change replace to False if you can't have twice the same large value

result[perm] = vals
```